# How to Set the defaults for Render Queue in After Effects

Tags: after-effects

I'm using After Effects CS3 (*yeah, I know it's old*) and I'm rendering my composition out. When I **Add to Render Queue** I have to change the settings like **Render Settings & Output Module** every time.

Is there a way to set these once and have AE use them every time you **Add to Render Queue**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it hasn't changed since CS3 (in fact It's been the same for as long as I can remember): in `Edit > Templates > Render Settings >`. Another way of getting to this dialogue is from the `Render Settings` drop-down in the render queue. At the bottom of the list of templates in the drop-down is `Make Template…`

Choosing that brings up the dialogue box pictured below. Up the top of the dialogue box you'll find `Movie Default`; set that to whatever template you want to be the default for renders. If you haven't got a template that has the settings you need then you can make one here - hit the `New` button, set all your settings and give it a name.  I find duplicating an existing one and modifying it a useful way to go.

Same goes for the output modules, which you get to from `Edit > Templates > Output Modules`, or from the `Output Modules` drop-down in the render queue.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for getting that posted, I'll delete my answer since you beat me to getting the screenshots up.  I can also confirm with 95% certainty that it has not changed substantially since CS3 off the top of my head.  It was like this prior to CS entirely.

Comment: I am pretty sure there is a way to get to that screen from the Render Queue settings as well, but I can't remember what link it is off the top of my head.

Comment: Yep, indeed there is, as always there's several ways of doing anything in After Effects. I've amended my answer.